# Solutions Zebra puzzle - Blood Donation

Tags: logical-deduction

Where can I check for solutions to the Blood Donation (Zebra puzzle) from Brainzilla?  I tried their website, but they did not have an 'answer section' available yet.  I emailed them and they gave me a link to this forum to see if I could get what I needed here. I am a teacher and like to use logic puzzles and the like to help my students with their critical thinking skills.

Thank you :)

Comment: Is it possible you could link or write out the question here so people can either help you solve it or point you in the right direction

Comment: I think that Brainzilla might be a little confused about what exactly this site is.  It is *not* a "forum", but rather a question-and-answer site.  As such, we host both questions *about* puzzles (like you have above), and puzzles to be solved.  What we *don't* do is host *discussions about* puzzles (except in our [chat rooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair)).  You could try asking your question there, or, if you have permission from Brainzilla, you could post the puzzle itself here as a question (with proper attribution, of course), and see if anyone can solve it.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and kind response.  I will try the chatroom and see if by doing that, I get the information I need.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone wanted to try this puzzle I found it at this [link](https://www.brainzilla.com/logic/zebra/blood-donation/).
I found the solution to be:

> #1, black shirt, Brooke, B-, 45 years, 130 lb, Actress |
>  #2, green shirt, Nichole, O-, 35 years, 160 lb, Chef | 
>  #3, purple shirt, Andrea, AB+, 30 years, 120 lb, Policewoman | 
>  #4, blue shirt, Meghan, A+, 25 years, 150 lb, Florist |
>  #5, red shirt, Kathleen, B+, 40 years, 140 lb, Engineer |

Hope this helps